# Skipping a mosque for another

Tags: salat, masjid, tajweed

As salamou aleykoum.
I am a little confused with a situation.
Days ago, I started skipping a mosque that's about 70m from my home for another another that's about 600m.
The reason is that in the nearest mosque the prayer is not done the way I think it should be. The Imam is too fast (as fast as you cannot understand the recitation unless you knew it). Plus they recite fatiha together (and louder for fajir, magrib and icha) after the taslim. Furthermore there's a man who loudly repeats the takbir of the Imam (as if there's a reason (current cut or mics failure) to do it).
I started skipping it without searching if it's allowed or not. So I am coming here and hoping for help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assalamu alaikum Youssouf,

According to a fatwa in islamweb (http://fatwa.islamweb.net), there is nothing wrong in skipping a close mosque to a further one if you feel more focused in your prayer in the distant mosque (because the Imam is too fast in the closer mosque).

However, reciting the fatiha after prayer and repeating the takbir of the Imam can be a subject of dispute among scholars. You'll hear many opinions about that.

Comment: Thann you vert much.